# CKFINDER 3 PHP on IIS uploaded file is corrupt

Tags: php, windows, iis, ckfinder

I have a new installation of CKFINDER 3 running on PHP on IIS. 
Whenever I try an upload a file via the CKFINDER upload button, I'm getting 'The uploaded file is corrupt'

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: There must be some logfile that explains more, because I've never seen 'the uploaded file is corrupt' being output. Where does that come from; iis?

Comment: CKFinder connector by default validates uploaded images (I believe it's about image). You can disable this behavior by altering `secureImageUploads` option in `config.php`, like:
`$config['secureImageUploads'] = false;`

Comment: You mentioned IIS, which means that it might be the same issue with temporary folder as here: https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder/issues/173